# Building a database website in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

Does anyone know of any good tutorials to build a database driven website?

I am trying to build a site, that will do the following:

1. I upload data into different tables (categories) into a MYSQL Database
2. The user on the front end selects a category
3. The database then prints out all of the data in that category

Seems simple right? But where do I start!

Comment: This question is way too broad. Perhaps you can split your question in multiple ones that ask more specific things.

Comment: [php manual](http://php.net/)

Comment: When you're sifting through the millions of tutorials that you can find on the web, ignore any that don't use mysqli or pdo

Comment: u can use various CMS like Wordpress, Joomla,Drupal etc and they all are well documented

Comment: This question is to broad and cannot be answered specifically. It's not a good fit.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - Apropos of nothing, I'd like to say how much I enjoy the quote on your network profile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, take up php basics from the ground up, learn your variables and what they do, if/else statements, loops n functions etc etc..and leanr how/why they operate.

once you have a handle on the basics, then do something like was suggested above like lynda.com(ive used em theyre great) and other tuts online/books etc.

To do what you want to do, not only will you need this (the basic concepts i put up above), but youll need to learn SQL/MySql as well which is another simple but easy to messup language especially at first depending on what/how/how much you want to extract from the DB, mixing it with php and printing on the page, seting up databases/tables etc etc...

ALSO, in order to organize and display your content, youll need to understand how to extract said data hence, learning the basic basics.

as far as W3Schools - for basics theyre fine.just my .02
If you do your homework, And can tackle what you need in an orderly fashion, in a few days you should be up n running.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could always get started with the PHP Tutorials on W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Before I get slated for suggesting them, they are a good start, especially if youre quite new to PHP or PHP with MySQL.

As for the printing it out, I guess you mean display it on a web page, the tutorials would cover this as well.

Once familiar with what you are doing, I highly recommend the tutorials put together on Lynda.com - http://www.lynda.com/

They are really well put together, and come with a video walk-through, so you get covered whatever your learning style.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools. See [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) why.

Comment: I strongly disagree that w3schools are good to start.

Comment: W3School's PHP/MySQL tutorials show you how to write code (using obsolete APIs) with major SQL injection issues. They don't mention SQL injection being a problem. Do not go near them.

Comment: Hence why I said, only as a good place to start. Without knowledge of the OP's current skill its hard to say where to start.

Comment: "Obsolete and insecure" is not a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could start off by looking at the example code here:
http://www.willfitch.com/mysqli-tutorial.html

Then look at the php documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Be careful not to get confused with the mysql_ and mysqli_ functions. mysqli_ is the one you want!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **PHP** to build your website,then maintain database on PHPMYADMIN of your server.Connect from your php code to mysql using mysql_connect function..follow this link...[php_on_server](http://dalibor.dvorski.net/downloads/docs/InstallingConfiguringDevelopingWithXAMPP.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I used a couple of the For Dummies series to learn PHP/MySQL/phpMyAdmin. I'm sure the purists will disapprove :)

However, one of my acquaintances works for Google, and he got in my ear that AJAX sites are a much better way to approach things than PHP-driven sites.

So I pretty much rewrote everything I'd done to minimise the need for page reloads. So I now use PHP on the server side, but the client side is never built with PHP. It starts as pure HTML, and then makes calls using Javascript.

I share this not because I have great expertise, but because it might save you some heartache later if you head down the AJAX road from the start :)